Alternate method to solve geometry question .
This question is from 1991 AHSME problem 23 ,
If ABCD is a 2*2 square , E is midpoint of AB ,F is the midpoint of BC , AF and DE intersect at I , BD and AF intersect at H , Find area of BEIH.
In the solution of problem it is solved by using coordinate geometry .
My question is can we solve using only Euclidian geometry + may be some trigonometry?
I tried to find it and found some bunch of similar triangles but I couldn't reach the answer .
Any idea how to solve it or can we even solve it ?

Welcome to MSE. From How to ask a good question: "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

@jjagmath will keep in mind next time

I don’t want to show you the answer, just show some hints:



Extend DE and CB to point G.
We can get that triangle BEG is actually congruent to triangle AED by proving using AAS or ASA.
So $GB=DA$.
We can know the ratio of GB:BF:FC.
As triangle FGI is similar to triangle ADI, $AD:GF=AI:IF$

Area of quadrilateral $BEIH$
$=$ Area of triangle $ABH - $ Area of triangle $AEI$
Can you continue from here?

Thank You so much , I got the answer!

Tha area ot $ABF$ is $1$.
Triangle $BHF$ is similar to $AHD$ with ratio $\displaystyle{1\over2}$, hence the height of $HF$ is $\displaystyle{2\over3}$ and its area $\displaystyle{1\over3}$.
Triangle $AEI$ is similar to $ABF$ with ratio $\displaystyle{AE\over AF}={1\over\sqrt5}$,
hence its area is $\displaystyle{1\over5}$.
In summary, the area of $EIBH$ is $\displaystyle1-{1\over3}-{1\over5}={7\over15}$.
